# Error 403 - Forbidden with symbolic link

Tags: linux, ssh, hosting

I'm deploying Laravel app in shared hosting.

I've deleted the orginal `public_html` folder and created symbolic link

`ln -s app/public public_html`

The symbolic link is success.

But I'm getting **Error 403 - Forbidden** when accessing the app url.

Comment: What web server are you using? Apache?

Comment: APACHE server Inmption Hosting

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have access to your web server configuration, you can override the configuration to permit symbolic links to be read. In the root directory of your web server, add the line below to the .htaccess file. Create the .htaccess file if it does not exist.

```
Options FollowSymLinks
```

This will only work if your main configuration permits the use of .htaccess config files.